# Stable QGIS version running on Windows 7

Tags: qgis, windows-7

I am having trouble with QGIS 3.10 constantly crashing on a Windows 7 machine.

We are looking at previous versions to install to get it to work. Upgrading to Windows 10 isn't an option.

What is the latest version that works on Windows 7?

Comment: have you considered running linux in a virtual machine?

Comment: Until 2 month ago i had Win 7 and QGIS 3.10.5 (i guess) ran flawlessly.

Comment: Doubt your issue, whatever it is, is as simple as Window - QGIS version incompatibility. I've had QGIS 3.10 and 3.12 running on Win 7 with no trouble. (Haven't upgraded that machine, now have 3.14 on another Win 10 machine). You're facing some incompatibility between something specific on your machine, and I'm afraid you'll have to yourself or with help fix the issue or roll back or forward versions until you happen to sidestep whatever is the glitch on your machine and install. Try the current 3.14, you might get lucky!

Comment: There shouldnt be an incompatibility between Win7 and QGIS. Must be something else. Did you try a clean newinstallation of QGIS? Meaning also to remove all QGIS profiles. Any hints in the crashlog? Drivers up to date? ....

Comment: Clean install and VM is not possible.

Comment: If a clean installation is not possible, I am afraid there will be no solution. May I ask why removing QGIS profiles is not possible for you?

Comment: it was a clean install. The VM isn't possible.

Comment: 3.16.8 is the last with Python 3.7, so works under Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

QGIS 3.14.x will work with the Python support and will have no problem with all the
Python plugins (including the Processing core plugin). That is the latest version for Windows 7 64-bit.